# IzPack does not create desktop shortcut in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut, izpack

Izpack 4.3.5 creates .desktop file and IzPackLocaleEnabledXdgDesktopIconScript.sh in install folder but does not create .desktop file on Desktop.

Contents of Unix_shortcutSpec.xml:

```
<shortcuts>
    <skipIfNotSupported/>
    <shortcut KdeUsername="root" applications="no" desktop="yes"
        encoding="UTF-8" initialState="normal" name="Desktop shortcut"
        programGroup="no" startMenu="no" startup="no"
        target="$INSTALL_PATH/src2/ec2ea" type="Application"/>
</shortcuts>
```

Comment: problem occurs if the install path contains spaces